# Disable place order button

Tags: onestepcheckout, create-order

I want to disable the place order button when they meets some condition and also it alert the message when the customer click the place order button.

Help me to finish my requirement.

Comment: I am using custom one step checkout module. In that module, the place order button is present in the review.phtml. We create a condition in the template file and check the check the condition. But the button was not disabled when my condition returns true.

Comment: what is your magento version ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override below template file and add disabled property

> checkout\onepage\review\button.phtml

And to alert messages, need to modify code in opcheckout.js under skin\js folder.

Else you can call your custom js function in onclick event.

Comment: I am using custom one step checkout module. In that module the button.phtml codings not been included. The button action specified in the review.phtml file itself.